# Using jquery ajax, how do you post an object containing a list other objects

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

Given these C# objects

```
class foo 
{
    int fooId {get; set;}
    string fooName {get;set;}
    List<bar> bars {get; set;}
}

class bar
{
    int barId {get; set;}
    string barName {get;set;}
}
```

and a WebApi method

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage AddFooBar(foo model)
{
    //...
}
```

Assuming we have a form where a user enters fooName and a list of bar items, what is the best way to serialize the data from the form and submit it to the WebApi method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to post foo and list of bars in one ajax call and into one WebApi controller action. I ended with two ajax posts and two controller actions. Two trips instead of one but it works. Below is my solution in case anyone may find it useful.

On the html side, I used two divs for the forms since this is Asp.net webforms which means we are limited to one form.

```
<div id="foo-form">
    <input type="text" name="fooName" value="" />
    <button type="button" class="btn-cancel">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-submit">Submit</button>
</div>

<div id="bar-form">
    <input type="text" class="foobar" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="foobar" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="foobar" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="foobar" value="" />
</div>
```

Javascript side (with Jquery ajax)

```
$("#foo-form .btn-submit").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fooBar.saveFoo();
});

var fooBar = new function () {

    //this posts foo
    this.saveFoo = function () {
        // serialize the form
        var serializedData = $("#foo-form :input").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/myapp/api/FooBar/AddFoo",
            data: serializedData,
            cache: false
        }).done(function (data) {
            if (data["Status"] === 'success') {
                //pass the id to the saveBars function
                fooBar.saveBars(data["Id"])
            }
            else {
                //handle logic error
            }
        }).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //handle ajax error
        }).always(function () {
            //something to do always
        });
    }


    //this posts bars
    this.saveBars = function (fooId) {

        //save all bars in array
        var arrBars = [];
        $('#bar-form .foobar').each(function () {
            arrBars.push(
                    {
                        "fooId": fooId,
                        "fooName": $(this).val()
                    }
                );
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/myapp/api/FooBar/AddBars",
            data: JSON.stringify(arrBars),
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        }).done(function (data) {
            if (data["Status"] === 'success') {
                //show success message
            }
            else {
                //handle logic error
            }
        }).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //handle ajax error
        }).always(function () {
            //something to do always
        });
    }
}
```

And now on the server side webapi controller C# code

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage AddFoo(Foo model)
{
    try
    {
        //validate
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Status = "error", Message = "Error in foo"});
        //save foo
        var db = new FooBarDB();
        var id = db.AddFoo(model);
        //return new fooId
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Status = "success", Id = id });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {                
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage AddBars(List<Bar> bars)
{
    try
    {
        //validate bars
        if (!this.ValidateBars(bars))
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Status = "error", Message = "Errors in bars"});
        //save bars
        var db = new FooBarDB();
        db.AddBars(bars);
        //show success
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Status = "success"});
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
    }
}

private bool ValidateBars(List<Bar> bars)
{
    //logic to validate bars
}
```

Comment: Now I prefer [AngularJs](http://curran.github.io/screencasts/introToAngular/exampleViewer/#/) as it makes the above trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend simply creating a dumb view with

```
<form id="f">
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.foo);
@for(var i = 0; i<Model.foo.bars.Length; i++){
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.foo.bars[i]);
}
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log($('#f').serialize());
});
```

So you can see the structure expected. Then You can fill your JSON how you wish

Comment: Multiple forms wouldn't work as this is not asp.net mvc but an asp.net webforms app with webapi webservices. I was looking for a single ajax method to post both foo and list of bars and a single webapi method to receive data from the browser which your answer doesn't address.